# Find coordinates of polygon points with arcpy

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system, geometry

I want to get the coordinates of polygons within a layer.
I manage to get them, by using the code from:

But, they are in decimal degrees, not in CRS units of the layer.

This is my code:

```
import arcpy 
arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\Users\Paul-PC\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb\polygon\polygon' 
infc = arcpy.env.workspace #(i tried creating a toolbox and setting infc = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) )
feature_dict = {}
i = 0
for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(infc, ["OID@", "SHAPE@"]):
    for part in row[1]:
        for pnt in part:
            feature_dict[(row[0], i)] = (pnt.Y, pnt.X)
            i+=1
print(feature_dict)
```

if i write:

```
desc = arcpy.Describe("polygon")
sr = desc.spatialreference
print(sr.name)
```

> > GCS_Dealul_Piscului_1970

if i try to execute the code to read the point coordinates of the polygon I get:

> {(10, 95): (47.12900645500008, 23.35278409500006), (7, 65): (47.11118189000007, 23.373594852000053), (12, 121): (47.14403012500003, 23.343077175000076), (5, 44): (47.097957059000066, 23.34153939600003), (15, 141): (47.12669242000004, 23.298300668000024), (6, 54): (47.07353351000006, 23.339277956000046), (16, 152): (47.129300690000036, 23.262708690000068), (11, 109): (47.11734513600004, 23.30749718900006), (12, 117): (47.12669242000004, 23.323025742000027), (13, 127): (47.12367716700004, 23.301768209000045), (14, 133): (47.13815038200005, 23.32483489400005), (9, 87): (47.10814861400007, 23.33433294100007), (7, 68): (47.09292271900006, 23.340853553000045), (13, 124): (47.14203911900006, 23.33974795100005), (5, 47): (47.10970147000006, 23.371239638000077), (10, 97): (47.106942513000035, 23.31639218600003), (15, 145): (47.151762802000064, 23.268990467000037), (1, 1): (46.754499242000065, 23.429154969000024), (11, 112): (47.140110296000046, 23.346092428000077), (2, 6): (46.75363668700004, 23.430731362000074), (11, 104): (47.134984366000026, 23.349861494000038), (3, 23): (47.04901950300007, 23.413890391000052), (14, 134): (47.12367716700004, 23.301768209000045), (9, 93): (47.12473250600004, 23.36192250600004), (4, 35): (47.04494891200005, 23.359615837000035), (12, 120): (47.13483360300006, 23.327699384000027), (10, 98): (47.11221920600008, 23.312472357000047), (8, 78): (47.10033910900006, 23.338403533000076), (3, 12): (47.04901950300007, 23.413890391000052), (6, 60): (47.071121308000045, 23.36189235300003), (2, 11): (46.75363668700004, 23.430731362000074), (8, 84): (47.11888291500003, 23.369309876000045), (4, 26): (47.05560783100003, 23.35902786300005), (3, 18): (47.04494891200005, 23.359615837000035), (14, 131): (47.14749766600005, 23.340363447000072), (9, 88): (47.10724403900008, 23.333126840000034), (5, 40): (47.06916139300006, 23.357067949000054), (4, 32): (47.074799916000075, 23.406955309000068), (5, 37): (47.05740190700004, 23.350585155000033), (10, 103): (47.130310724000026, 23.354987424000058), (8, 75): (47.11888291500003, 23.369309876000045), (5, 50): (47.05560783100003, 23.35902786300005), (15, 150): (47.12669242000004, 23.298300668000024), (6, 57): (47.08800672400008, 23.34666532600005), (11, 113): (47.134984366000026, 23.349861494000038), (8, 81): (47.10724403900008, 23.333126840000034), (4, 31): (47.094956883000066, 23.394457086000045), (3, 17): (47.04223518400005, 23.361424989000056), (9, 91): (47.11478217100006, 23.32875472300003), (7, 64): (47.11301824800006, 23.376516330000072), (14, 138): (47.14282402400005, 23.324231844000053), (5, 43): (47.09433875600007, 23.343047022000064), (1, 5): (46.75417206600008, 23.428679077000027), (6, 55): (47.08664986100007, 23.331136773000026), (16, 153): (47.13729567900003, 23.255475129000047), (6, 58): (47.08182545600005, 23.34952981600003), (11, 108): (47.11221920600008, 23.312472357000047), (12, 118): (47.11734513600004, 23.30749718900006), (4, 28): (47.081810380000036, 23.385260564000077), (13, 130): (47.14403012500003, 23.343077175000076), (9, 86): (47.12356044000006, 23.35997261500006), (7, 71): (47.10033910900006, 23.338403533000076), (13, 123): (47.14403012500003, 23.343077175000076), (5, 46): (47.111827223000034, 23.37003353600005), (1, 0): (46.75417206600008, 23.428679077000027), (2, 7): (46.75283361900006, 23.43227801200004), (11, 107): (47.12216954100006, 23.327699384000027), (3, 22): (47.05173323100007, 23.412835053000038), (14, 135): (47.12669242000004, 23.298300668000024), (9, 92): (47.130310724000026, 23.354987424000058), (7, 74): (47.11301824800006, 23.376516330000072), (13, 126): (47.12066191400004, 23.30448193600006), (15, 148): (47.13317521400006, 23.308100240000044), (10, 99): (47.12216954100006, 23.327699384000027), (8, 79): (47.09310250200008, 23.327096334000032), (3, 15): (47.02142993900003, 23.375445916000047), (1, 3): (46.75327976800003, 23.429690348000065), (6, 61): (47.05559275500008, 23.355108034000068), (2, 8): (46.75259567300003, 23.430701619000047), (4, 27): (47.072915383000066, 23.365661420000038), (3, 21): (47.06304043000006, 23.412232002000053), (16, 151): (47.14224495800005, 23.273939746000053), (4, 33): (47.07163390100004, 23.40273395500003), (15, 142): (47.134059612000044, 23.29107186500005), (7, 73): (47.11888291500003, 23.369309876000045), (5, 36): (47.04806969900005, 23.35721871100003), (10, 100): (47.12518479400006, 23.333126840000034), (8, 76): (47.11773244700004, 23.367416185000025), (5, 49): (47.072915383000066, 23.365661420000038), (6, 62): (47.05640375400003, 23.35308053700004), (12, 114): (47.140110296000046, 23.346092428000077), (8, 82): (47.10814861400007, 23.33433294100007), (4, 24): (47.04494891200005, 23.359615837000035), (3, 16): (47.03107874800003, 23.368661596000038), (9, 90): (47.106942513000035, 23.31639218600003), (7, 67): (47.09433875600007, 23.343047022000064), (5, 42): (47.08800672400008, 23.34666532600005), (15, 146): (47.16051921900004, 23.276604742000075), (5, 39): (47.071121308000045, 23.36189235300003), (1, 4): (46.75327976800003, 23.428708820000054), (5, 52): (47.04806969900005, 23.35721871100003), (16, 154): (47.14833637800007, 23.264992973000062), (6, 59): (47.06916139300006, 23.357067949000054), (11, 111): (47.13181835000006, 23.331016163000072), (12, 119): (47.12066191400004, 23.30448193600006), (4, 29): (47.10970147000006, 23.371239638000077), (13, 129): (47.14749766600005, 23.340363447000072), (10, 94): (47.130310724000026, 23.354987424000058), (9, 85): (47.12473250600004, 23.36192250600004), (7, 70): (47.09310250200008, 23.327096334000032), (5, 45): (47.099163160000046, 23.343499310000027), (15, 143): (47.14281602900007, 23.280792594000047), (11, 106): (47.12518479400006, 23.333126840000034), (12, 116): (47.13181835000006, 23.331016163000072), (14, 132): (47.14515065900008, 23.336464387000035), (7, 69): (47.08664986100007, 23.331136773000026), (13, 125): (47.13483360300006, 23.327699384000027), (15, 147): (47.14281602900007, 23.297734356000035), (10, 96): (47.11478217100006, 23.32875472300003), (14, 137): (47.141316397000026, 23.32151811600005), (3, 14): (47.01886697300006, 23.37725506700008), (1, 2): (46.75423155200008, 23.429690348000065), (2, 9): (46.75274438900004, 23.429154969000024), (11, 105): (47.13355879100004, 23.34742705000008), (3, 20): (47.074799916000075, 23.406955309000068), (16, 155): (47.14224495800005, 23.273939746000053), (12, 122): (47.140110296000046, 23.346092428000077), (4, 34): (47.04805262700006, 23.36463087900006), (14, 136): (47.13317521400006, 23.308100240000044), (7, 72): (47.10184673600003, 23.341268023000055), (10, 101): (47.134984366000026, 23.349861494000038), (8, 77): (47.10184673600003, 23.341268023000055), (5, 48): (47.081810380000036, 23.385260564000077), (3, 13): (47.04479814900003, 23.41675488100003), (6, 63): (47.05740190700004, 23.350585155000033), (12, 115): (47.13770388100005, 23.341717128000028), (2, 10): (46.75378540300005, 23.429273942000066), (14, 139): (47.15066368200007, 23.33734819400007), (8, 83): (47.12473250600004, 23.36192250600004), (4, 25): (47.04806969900005, 23.35721871100003), (3, 19): (47.07163390100004, 23.40273395500003), (9, 89): (47.10030895700004, 23.32166887900007), (7, 66): (47.10970147000006, 23.371239638000077), (5, 41): (47.08182545600005, 23.34952981600003), (14, 140): (47.14749766600005, 23.340363447000072), (5, 38): (47.05559275500008, 23.355108034000068), (15, 144): (47.14548102500004, 23.277175813000042), (10, 102): (47.13227063800008, 23.352273696000054), (6, 53): (47.05740190700004, 23.350585155000033), (5, 51): (47.05008537900005, 23.357702474000064), (15, 149): (47.12810445400004, 23.30043513800007), (6, 56): (47.09433875600007, 23.343047022000064), (11, 110): (47.12669242000004, 23.323025742000027), (8, 80): (47.10030895700004, 23.32166887900007), (4, 30): (47.11301824800006, 23.376516330000072), (13, 128): (47.13815038200005, 23.32483489400005)}

The coordinates are in decimal, not in Stereo 70.

Comment: Your description is confusing. When using the `shape@` key from a DA cursor, the units should be that of the source *unless* the `spatial_reference` parameter is used (or a layer path is used, and the data frame's spatial reference is forcing on-the-fly projection), but you're indicating that a query is returning something different. Please [Edit] the question to contain a less redacted "path" and to report all the spatial reference `name`s involved.

Comment: The code that you have presented looks like it is trying to open a SearchCursor on a workspace rather than something like a feature class or table. I would expect an error at that point.

Comment: @Vince I edited the question.

Comment: @PolyGeo How should I write it to open the Search Cursor on the feature class?

Comment: It looks like you have a feature class named polygon in a feature dataset named polygon in a file geodatabase. Try copying that to something like C:\Temp\testFC and then set inFc = r”C:\Temp\testFC”.

Comment: @PolyGeo do you mean to export as shapefile?

Comment: Oops - that should have been C:\Temp\test.gdb\testFC.

Comment: @PolyGeo done, still the same

Comment: Still the same as what?  The code you are presenting has not yet been modified. We cannot see what the print statement is reporting. Are you running your tests against a simple feature class with perhaps just a single triangle, square or rectangle (so that only a few coordinates are reported)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104278/discussion-between-paul-nicoara-and-polygeo).

Comment: Decimal degrees is the correct units for a feature class in GCS_Dealul_Piscului_1970 (the `GCS_ `part indicates a geographic CS)

Comment: Ok, Thank you @Vince